# Wine isn't showing up anywhere on Ubuntu

Tags: wine

I've just installed wine on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, But I can't find it's icon in the app menu. and when I try to run an exe file, it doesn't open automatically either. Also I can't find it anywhere when I try using the "open with other application" option in the right click menu (I did go to "view all applications" but still no luck). Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my problem by installing wine from HQ repository.
see how : https://vitux.com/how-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu/

after installing, I found wine by right clicking on the exe file and selecting "open with other application"

Comment: How to un-install when using the first method ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running with command line instead:

```
wine <PATH_TO_FILE>
```